# C# When debugging I get "The requested operation requires elevation", why? It was OK yesterday!

Tags: c#, windows-vista

C#

When I try to debug my program today I get "The requested operation requires elevation" (Vista of course). Why today? I've not changed anything the reads/writes to the registry or hard drive, where should I look?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it is just Visual Studio complaining (and not an underlying security issue of your code), you can set Visual Studio to [automatically run as admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258728/request-admin-privileges-for-java-app-on-windows-vista#258863).

Answer (score 0):

Just compiled the exe and now the exe require elevation outside of VS! The only interaction with the local PC is a read from the user part of the registry but that was in days ago when it worked without elevation.

Thanks

Comment: Did you change the EXE output name? Vista will auto-elevate for things with Setup or Install in the name. Did you (or someone else) add a manifest file asking for elevation? If it worked fine a few days ago, and now doesn't, look in source control to see what's changed...