# Run java application as administrator priviledge in XP

Tags: java

I have created a small program in java which reads the UninstallString of an application from registry and then using

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec("command")
```

to uninstall this application. But this task require administrator priviledge.

On Windows Vista, 7 and 8 this work fine by creating a bat file with the following command "java -jar java_app.jar", right click on the bat file and run as administrator.

But on XP, my account is an administrator account but still it fails to run the java program as administrator.

Can anyone provide me with some solutions which can solve this problem?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642892/java-getruntime-exec-an-exe-that-requires-uac

Answer (score 1):

You can use RunAs command:

```
RUNAS /TrustLevel:Unrestricted notepad.exe
```

You can find trust levels available on you system:

```
RUNAS /ShowTrustLevels
```

The following liks explains that in more details http://blog.johnmuellerbooks.com/2011/04/26/simulating-users-with-the-runas-command.aspx

Comment: I tried adding this to the bat file: runas /TrustLevel:Unrestricted "java -jar java_app.jar" to launch the program with elevation but still the java application does not run as administrator

Comment: What about Process p = Runtime.getRuntime.exec("RUNAS /TrustLevel:Unrestricted command") ?

Comment: I tried this also but unfortunately its the same. Will wrapping the .jar file to .exe do the job?

Comment: execute RUNAS /ShowTrustLevels and try with an other trust level.