# Running Windows commandline from Java as an Administrator - Creating a .manifest file

Tags: java, command-line, manifest, administrator

I am running Windows 7 Pro and working on a Java application in Eclipse. I need Eclipse to send user-specified commands (such as 'chkdsk C:') to the command prompt and then output to the console in Eclipse whatever the command prompt would have printed. I have the sending commands working and the receiving text back. However, when I to run chkdsk I need to have admin privileges for the command session. I see from the thread here:

[Java: run as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385866/java-run-as-administrator)

that one way to do this is through a .manifest file.  However, I am having trouble understanding how to create a manifest file for Java:

Does the .manifest file just go into the Eclipse workspace with the .CLASS files? If I put it there will it run automatically to start my program in admin mode whenever I run the program?

The link given from the above thread:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx

seems to be Visual-Studio specific, will there example code work for a Java program .manifest file? Do I need to create the .manifest file in Visual Studio or is it just a text file?

Also, the name of the manifest file is yourProgram.exe.manifest ... Java as I understand it doesn't create executables of the .exe variety does it? Should the manifest file be named as above or does it need a name like yourProgram.CLASS.manifest?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: As described by Luke Woodward, `Java manifest (.MF)` and `Windows style manifest (.manifest)` are two different files. Usually, we create an EXE launcher for the jar. EXE launcher like Launch4J can embed into EXE a Window style manifest. See the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258728/request-admin-privileges-for-java-app-on-windows-vista

Answer (score 2):

The application manifest described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx), and the Java manifest file (in the JAR file at META-INF/MANIFEST.MF), are two completely separate concepts that share only a name.  There's nothing in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF that will help a Java executable gain elevation.

Besides, its the JVM that needs the elevation, not the class files. Putting the .manifest file with all your class files will not achieve anything.

If I had to do something like this, my preferred approach would be to use a program such as `elevate.exe` to call `CHKDSK`.  `elevate.exe` can be found at [this blog article](http://jpassing.com/2007/12/08/launch-elevated-processes-from-the-command-line/) linked to in the question you've mentioned.  I haven't tested `elevate.exe`, and the author originally wrote it for Windows Vista, so I don't know how well it works on Windows 7.

It seems that `CHKDSK` is the only part of your app that requires elevation.  If so, it would make sense from a security point-of-view not to have the whole app elevated all of the time when most of the time it can manage without.