# Run command prompt as Administrator

Tags: java, command-line, command-prompt

I am developing a small shutdown scheduler project in which i have to put the computer in `"Stand By"` mode. The command that i am using is

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState ");
```

This command requires Admin rights which i don't know how to get. Also while searching for previous answers i found i can use `elevate.exe` as

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:/elevate Rundll32.exe Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState ");
```

`Elevate.exe` is doing the task but is consuming too much of time i.e. making the software slow. Is there any other speedy way? I am using Netbeans IDE.

Comment: [Run command line with Admin rights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539978/running-windows-commandline-from-java-as-an-administrator-creating-a-manifest)

Comment: The windows "shutdown" command might suit you better as it doesn't require admin access.  To hibernate:  shutdown /h

Comment: @mikeslattery there is difference between standby and hibernate and i want to stand by.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a few options

A. Create a shortcut with admin priv.

The shortcut will run `cmd /c Rundll32.exe Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState`

Your Java code will run the shortcut:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("cmd /c start \"\" \"myshortcut.lnk\"")
```

Right click the shortcut icon > properties > advanced > run as administrator

B. Run the java process as administrator

Again, create a shortcut and set to run as administrator.  Any processes spawned will also have admin privileges.  Your java code will run:

```
rt.exec("cmd /c Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState")
```

C. Use JNA to directly call SetSuspendState routine.  The Java process will require admin priv (like B), but you won't have to spawn a process.  If you like this, I can provide source code.

D. **Use [wizmo](http://www.grc.com/wizmo/wizmo.htm) utility**: `wizmo quiet standby`

Comment: `rt.exec("cmd /c start \"\" \"myshortcut.lnk\"")` but i have to make the shortcut as `cmd /c Rundll32.exe Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState` but it takes a lot of time to execute the command. Is there any way by which i can increase the execution speed?

Comment: Ok one thing more if i want to use `sleep` option with `setsuspendstate`then i have to set `hibernation off`. This will again require a new admin shortcut and hence two popups for acceptance. Is there a way to achieve this task in 1 shortcut or command?

Comment: Wizmo working  perfectly it even has more advance options. Thanks

Comment: is there any way to get the output of the command (in my case its w32tm /query /configuration) when using a shortcut/lnk?  doesnt seem like it unfortunately

Answer (score 11):

```
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("runas /profile /user:Administrator \"cmd.exe /c Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState\"");
```

Also plz see comments

[Running as admin without Admin rights](https://superuser.com/questions/244959/run-as-administrator-shortcut-without-password-prompt)

Comment: @TechExchange runas /user:Administrator cmd.exe /c Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState will require to enter Administrator password which i donot have.

Comment: @TechExchange I don't have any passwords for my admin account and it asks for a password.

Comment: [Running as Admin without AdminPasswd](http://superuser.com/questions/244959/run-as-administrator-shortcut-without-password-prompt)

Comment: sometimes the user has to be be specified as domain\user as seen in the runas help documentation (runas /?). Using this approach or running as Administrator didn't work for me, in a corporate environment, an account may have admin rights or if it doesn't it would not be possible to get Administrator passwords. In the former case, the command still didn't run. Running in elevated access level appears to be the solution

Answer (score 6):

Add parameter `/savecred`

```
runas /profile /user:Administrator /savecred
```

Input the password one times. In future OS will not ask you password.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Windows 10.  IDK why but `runas` isn't working and isn't reporting any errors.

**I found this answer on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/1200474/345864)**:

```
    powershell -Command "Start-Process 'cmd.exe /c Powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState ' -Verb runAs"
```

- No password required if you have permission to elevate.
- No shortcut required on client machine
- No dependency on `runas`
- Requires `powershell`

Powershell is installed by default on Windows since Windows 8 and Windows Server 2008 R2, according to an answer found on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/a/615293/181145).