# error while running sc create command through java

Tags: java, windows

I want to register the service in windows and after register wants to start also.

using following command in the code::

```
cmd.exe /C sc create "<service name>" binpath="D:\\abc\\xyz.exe -zglaxservice xyz"
```

I execute above command through `runtime.exec()`.

upon running the code it gives the help of sc command.

Code ::

```
Process proc = null;
String[] cmdStr = new String[] { "cmd.exe","/C","sc", "create", "\""+servicename+"\"", "binpath= \"D:\\SCCode\\"+exeName+".exe -zglaxservice "+laxName+"\"" };
proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArr);
```

Please help...

Comment: plz format your post

Comment: Please add your Java code - especially are you using the array or single-string command variant? Is your Java process running with elevated permission?

Comment: @eckes added the code in the post

Comment: what does the -zglaxservice  mean?

Answer (score 0):

Two issues with the command

```
cmd.exe /C sc create "" binpath="D:\abc\xyz.exe -zglaxservice xyz"
```

1. Service name is missing
2. After = (equals symbol) you need to put a space.

So the correct command would be as follows:

`cmd.exe /C sc create "ServiceName" binpath= "D:\abc\xyz.exe -zglaxservice xyz"`

I observed you did some modification, although still you command line string is not correct (couple of space is missing). The correct one would be as follows:

```
String[] cmdStr = new String[] { "cmd.exe ","/C ","sc ", "create ", "\""+servicename+"\"", " binpath= \"D:\\SCCode\\"+exeName+".exe -zglaxservice "+laxName+"\"" };
```

I tried above and I was getting issue as

```
'"sc "' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

which comes if your java is not running in admin mode, since sc command requires your cmd command to run in admin mode.

If you are facing the same issue, please check below link:

[Run command prompt as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596599/run-command-prompt-as-administrator)

Comment: tried you inputs but doesnt work. service name i have already added. you can also check the code i have added in the post.

Comment: @Anjali  added more clues.

Comment: password is needed if i run it as an admin,I want to do this without  providing password....is there any way?

Comment: @Anjali check this --> http://superuser.com/questions/244959/run-as-administrator-shortcut-without-password-prompt

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me:

`cmd.exe /C sc create "cdfa$" binpath= "F:\Connect_Direct\Sterling Commerce\FileAgent\cdfa$.exe -zglaxservice cdfa$"`