# Running a process as administrator

Tags: java, windows

I'm trying to run a command line command as an administrator.

I have created a shortcut of devcon.exe named devconShort. In the shortcut's properties I have checked the box to run as administrator. I tried the shortcut in command line directly and it worked but windows still asked me if I want to allow the application to make changes to my computer.

But when I run it in my Java code I get an error that windows can not find the file.

[image]

I am using the code below to run the shortcut. Is there any other way to do this?

```
    try
    {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = null;
        pr = rt.exec("cmd /c start \"\" \"C:\\devconShort.lnk enable *DEV_4222*\"");

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

        String line = null;

        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exited with error code " + exitVal);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have also tried the following

```
pr = rt.exec("runas /noprofile /user:Administrator \"C:\\devconShort.lnk enable *DEV_4222*\"");
```

and it gives the following message

[image]

Comment: What is the exact error / stack trace?

Comment: @dimo414 I have added image of the error

Comment: You've got the entire command line quoted, so it is trying to run a file named `devconShort.lnk disable *DEV_4222*`.  Try moving the last quote mark to just after `.lnk`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston this works if I start the java program as an administrator. Thanks

Comment: Note that if the Java program is running as administrator, you shouldn't need the shortcut - you can just run devcon.exe directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run command prompt as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596599/run-command-prompt-as-administrator)

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the CMD window as administrator - Give this a shot:

```
try{

    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

    Process pr = null;

    pr = rt.exec("runas /noprofile /user:Administrator cmd /c start \"\" \"C:\\devconShort.lnk enable *DEV_4222*\"");

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

    String line = null;

    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Exited with error code " + exitVal);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```