# Running cmd as administrator in Java

Tags: java, cmd

I'm trying to write a function that has the name of a service as parameter. The problem is that i can only start and stop a service in cmd ( in windows) only if i run it as administrator. How can i run cmd in java as administrator? Can you please help me?? Thanks

```
public String stop(String name) {
    try {
        List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();

        command.add("cmd.exe");
                    command.add("/c");
                    command.add("runas");
                    command.add("/user:Administrator");
                    command.add("\"net");
            command.add("stop");
                    command.add(name + "\"");
        System.out.println(command);
        Process servicesProcess = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
        InputStream input = servicesProcess.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        String line;
        StringBuffer queryResult = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            queryResult.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        servicesProcess.destroy();
        System.out.println(queryResult.toString());
        if (queryResult.toString().toLowerCase().contains("failed") || queryResult.toString().toLowerCase().contains("error")) {
            return "Failed @stop";
        }
        System.out.println("Stop service completed succesfully!");
        return "Succes @stop";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "Failed @stop";



        }   
}
```

I also tried with  this and still doesn't work

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();

        command.add("cmd.exe");
        command.add("/c");
                    command.add("Powrprof.dll");
                    command.add(",");
                    command.add("SetSuspendState");

        command.add("net");
        command.add("stop");

        command.add(name);


        System.out.println(command);
        Process servicesProcess = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
```

Comment: you can't do run a dll via cmd like that. you'd need to call `rundll`...

Comment: I don't understand. I dont want to call rundll, i just need to run my cmd in java as administrator.

Comment: why don't you add the desired permissions in the OS? Should be more natural..

Comment: This should be an application. It's mandatory to do this in a java application.

Comment: `cmd.exe /c powerprof.dll` is not going to work... to "run" a dll, you need to use "rundll.exe", not "cmd.exe"

Comment: It doesnt work with rundll.exe /C ...

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596599/run-command-prompt-as-administrator. I think it will help.

Comment: I did look at that and it's not working. I searched for 5 hours and then i asked you guys.

Comment: In the end i just opened NetBeans as administrator and worked with net start[name].