# Fail to Execute chef-client.bat from java

Tags: java

I fail to execute chef recipe with the command ***chef-client.bat -z -o "recipe[cookbook::recipe]"*** inside java method in specific folder (e.g C:\CItool\chef-project. The problem is that chef-client.bat requires to be run as Administrator. How can I do that ?

```
String line;
Process process=Runtime.getRuntime()
                       .exec("chef-client.bat -z -o \"recipe[cookbook::recipe]\"",
                              null, new File("C:\CItool\chef-project"));
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.print(line);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596599/run-command-prompt-as-administrator

Comment: Removing the chef tags as this is not a question about Chef beyond the incidental fact that Chef needs to be run as an admin account.