# Using SIGAR to get oracle process info, from a web app server (glassfish4)

Tags: web, access-denied, glassfish-4, sigar

I have been working on a web monitor using  sigar to gather the System information, but now i need to get the Oracle's RAM and CPU usage. I did it using  sigar.getProcCpu(pid).getTotal() function.

But when i deploy the app on glassfish 4, i get the error message: org.hyperic.sigar.SigarPermissionDeniedException: Access is denied.

is there any walkaround for this? can i give sigar access to the info that im requesting?

Answer (score 1):

I got exact the same problem as yours.
I found this post after I asked [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184353/sigar-api-throws-org-hyperic-sigar-sigarpermissiondeniedexception/20207100#20207100) and find my answer.
And here's my answer for my own question:

> The OS does not allow your program to access process information until you run the program with Admin privilege, so I need to provide Admin privilege.
>
> There are some methods to provide Admin privilege, including ask user to right click on the icon and select "run as administrator".
>
> But the better way might be wrapping your java application in an .exe like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258728/request-admin-privileges-for-java-app-on-windows-vista) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385866/java-run-as-administrator?answertab=votes#tab-top) said.
>
> However, I probably have to hack the OS as excowboy said [here](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/357308) as I want to show the information on web page and can't wrapping my app in an .exe file.
>
> I think I have to give up. Just put these links for those who may need it. :) Oh, the total CPU usage is accessible if you want,BTW.

Hope this would help you and sorry for my poor English. ;)