# Sigar API throws "org.hyperic.sigar.SigarPermissionDeniedException"

Tags: java, sigar

I'm new to Sigar and I'm trying to use Sigar API to gather CPU usage.

But Sigar throws this:

> org.hyperic.sigar.SigarPermissionDeniedException: Access is denied.

Can anyone help me? Here's my code:

```
public void pollCheck() {
    SysInfo sys=new SysInfo();
    System.out.println("Total CPU:"+sys.getTotalCPU());
}
```

And here's SysInfo.java:

```
import org.hyperic.sigar.ProcCpu;
import org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar;
public class SysInfo {
public long[] getProList(){
    long[] result=null;
    try{
    Sigar sigar=new Sigar();
    result=sigar.getProcList();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error in SysInfo.getProList:"+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
public double getTotalCPU(){
    long[] procs=getProList();
    double total=0.0;
    try{
    Sigar sigar=new Sigar();
    for(long proc:procs){
        ProcCpu temp=sigar.getProcCpu(proc);
        temp.gather(sigar, proc);
        total+=temp.getPercent();
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error in SysInfo.getTotalCPU:"+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return total;
}
}
```

And the error info is:

```
[2013-11-25T10:53:24.651+0800] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=Thread-3] [timeMillis: 1385348004651] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Error in SysInfo.getTotalCPU:org.hyperic.sigar.SigarPermissionDeniedException: Access is denied.]]
[2013-11-25T10:53:24.655+0800] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=Thread-4] [timeMillis: 1385348004655] [levelValue: 1000] [[
org.hyperic.sigar.SigarPermissionDeniedException: Access is denied.
at org.hyperic.sigar.ProcCpu.gather(Native Method)
at org.hyperic.sigar.ProcCpu.fetch(ProcCpu.java:30)
at org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getProcCpu(Sigar.java:488)
at bean.SysInfo.getTotalCPU(SysInfo.java:32)
at bean.indexBean.pollCheck(indexBean.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:326)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:536)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:269)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at org.primefaces.component.poll.Poll.broadcast(Poll.java:216)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)]]
[2013-11-25T10:53:24.658+0800] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=Thread-3] [timeMillis: 1385348004658] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Total CPU:0.0]]
```

Sorry for my poor English.

And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know why...

The OS does not allow your program to access process information until you run the program with Admin privilege, so I need to provide Admin privilege.

There are some methods to provide Admin privilege, including ask user to right click on the icon and select "run as administrator".

But the better way might be wrapping your java application in an .exe like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258728/request-admin-privileges-for-java-app-on-windows-vista) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385866/java-run-as-administrator?answertab=votes#tab-top) said.

However, I probably have to hack the OS as excowboy said [here](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/357308) as I want to show the information on web page and can't wrapping my app in an .exe file.

I think I have to give up. Just put these links for those who may need it. :)
Oh, the total CPU usage is accessible if you want,BTW.